# Make video fit 100% with any screen resolution

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video with the following properties, Frame width: 1920 and Frame Height: 1080. I need its width and height to be 100% thus filling up the whole screen. And it needs to be responsive too. So far, I have this code :

```
<video class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-custom videosize embed-responsive-item" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="~/Videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

css:

```
   .videosize {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100vh;
}
```

With the code above it fits perfectly with a 1680 x 1050 screen resolution, however with other resolution, it takes up 100% of the height then the width adjusts leaving white spaces on both sides.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: check fitvids  http://fitvidsjs.com/

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Found a good solution here: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/OVGWLG

So your CSS would be:

```
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container video {
  /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 

  /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* Center the video */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
  <video>
    <source src="~/Videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Any idea if we could achieve the same thing for an embedded Youtube iframe like this?

Comment: ` /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; ` Did the trick for me

Comment: This won't work with vertical videos, for example 1080x1920 resolution. The video looks slightly zoomed in so parts of the top and bottom are cut off. I'm still looking for a solution myself, will return here if I find one.

Comment: @StefanMidjich - that's just the way it goes.

Comment: @StefanMidjich Setting the body's margin and padding to 0 fixed that for me.

Answer (score 29):

You can now use the object-fit property. This property has been designed especially to manage responsive size for `<img>` and `<video>` elements. It is now supported by all modern browsers.

```
.videosize {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: can you post a full example of this?

Comment: For now, @raumus solution is definitely better than my `object-fit` solution because it is not yet supported by Microsoft Edge (v16.16299)... :-(

Comment: Ofc Microsoft is behind even with their new browser. Otherwise object-fit is really nice!!!

Comment: In my case I wanted the video to fit neatly in the available space, i.e. scale up only until it touched either the vertical or horizontal edges. I found `object-fit: contain` did that perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

```
.video-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        object-fit: fill;
    }

    .video-container video {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I Set the height of the video Tag and it solved the problem:

```html
<video height="600" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true" plays-inline="" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; min-width:100%; z-index: -100; object-fit: cover;">
      <source src="assets/vid/grapes.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Comment: What is that height for? Why 600? Also, plays-inline should be playsinline

Answer (score 1):

This worked amazingly: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/

```
video {
    /* override other styles to make responsive */
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using object-fit: cover; was my solution.

As of 2021 it is supported by all major browsers.
[object-fit support](https://caniuse.com/?search=object-fit)

CSS Example:

```
.video-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;
}

.video-wrapper video {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I guess this can help?

```css
*{
    margin: 0 !important;
}

html{
    height: 100vh;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper video{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red; /* I added bg color here so you can see how the video cover the page */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <video>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was dealing with a **16:9** (landscape) aspect ratio video, which I wanted to be responsive even on **mobile screens**. Web view was fine but mobile view seems to show a lot of padding on the sides.

I achieved responsiveness, that is 100% width size, by cropping the landscape video into another video with 9:16 (vertical) aspect ratio, which I then rendered on my React (Next.js) app conditionally with respect to the **screen size**:

```
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);
  const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true);
    const updateScreenWidth = () => {
      setScreenWidth(window.innerWidth);
    };
    if (isClient) {
      updateScreenWidth();
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateScreenWidth);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateScreenWidth);
    };
  }, [isClient]);

  const videoAspectRatio = screenWidth < 720 ? "landingvideoVertical" : "landingvideo";
  return (
    <Base title={title}>
      {isClient && (
        <div className="videoContainer">
          <div className="titleContainer">
            <h1 className="landingTitle font-primary font-bold">
              {banner.title}
            </h1>
            <p className="landingSubTitle text-center">
              {markdownify(banner.content)}
            </p>
          </div>

          <ReactPlayer
            className="reactPlayer"
            url={`videos/${videoAspectRatio}.mp4`} //<---- Render based on screen size
            playing={true}
            controls={false}
            volume={null}
            muted={true}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            loop={true}
            playsinline={true}
          />
        </div>
      )}
```

Here's its corresponding CSS if you need it:

```
.videoContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
#reactPlayer { //<---- ik it should've been class instead of id, but somehow only this way works
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  z-index: -10;
}
.titleContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use an iframe?

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */
 
.flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.flexible-container iframe,   
.flexible-container object,  
.flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="URL" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh please dont. This is outdated, even for a 2016 answer