# Make video fit 100% with any choosen screen resolution

Tags: javascript, css, styles, electron

I have a problem with my application. Every time when I change my screen resolution, my video starts to move out of position (in the center of the screen). Any suggestions on how to make my video stay in the same location even though I change to any other resolution?

```
.fullscreen-bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;}

.fullscreen-bg_video {
    position: absolute; 
    border:  6px solid;
    padding: 8.5px;
    background: #dddddd;
         border-top-left-radius: 1em;
         border-top-right-radius: 1em;
         border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

Comment: Provide HTML code or jsfiddle

Comment: The code seems fine, considering you are applying the width (and height) to the HTML directly.

Comment: Can you please paste your code into a JsFiddle and link it here? :)

Comment: You can either use CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949747/make-video-fit-100-with-any-screen-resolution or get FitVids js and it will resize videos for you (you can set it to resize other types of presentations too): http://fitvidsjs.com/

Comment: i am not sure how to add it as comment, so i added it down (: thanks guys.
waiting to ur replies

Comment: Wich option you need:
- just only center it vertically and make it 100% wide,
- center it vertically and horizontally and width and height auto (/maximum original size)
- fit full window -  100% high and wide?

Answer (score 0):

html code:

```
 <md-list flex class="side-actions">
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="action in $ctrl.sideActions" ng-click="action.callback()">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="{{ action.icon }}" aria-label="{{ action.display }}"></md-icon>
            <span flex>{{ action.display }}</span>
        </md-list-item>
        <div class="fullscreen-bg" style="visibility:hidden" id="video_div">
        <video class="fullscreen-bg_video" id="video" controls>
            <source id="videoSrc" type="video/mp4"> {{$ctrl.videoSrc}}
        </video>

        <span>
            <md-button  flex-offset="45" flex="5" class="close" id="closeButton" ng-click="$ctrl.closeVideo()">
                <md-icon class="control in-line s-24" md-svg-src="app/assets/icon_remove.svg"></md-icon>
                <span>Close</span>
            </md-button>
        </span>

    </div>
    </md-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your CSS I assume your HTML looks something like this:

```html
    <div class="fullscreen-bg">
        <div class="fullscreen-bg_video">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If my assumption is correct, all you have to do is give the video a `width`of 100%

```css
.fullscreen-bg .fullscreen-bg-video video{
  width:100%
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: its not working, its tot big and got out the borders of the screen, i need it a little bit smaller (and in smaller screen it's works different

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: i did a little change and it work better, now i want to add exit button in the upper right corner, can u help me how to do that ?