# Fitting background video

Tags: html, css, background

How can i fit this video on the whole screen?

I have used the below code

```
<style>

*{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
#sky-video{
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       z-index: -100;
   }

</style>

<body>
   <video src="videos/Sky.mp4" autoplay muted loop id="sky-video">You brower does not support vidoes</video>
   
</body>
```

[Here you can see there is a gap in right and left of the video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj1cN.png)
Is this because the video size is too small to fit in the whole screen?

Comment: Try with width as 100vw. Also for images and videos height should be auto, instead of 100%.

Comment: Answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949747/make-video-fit-100-with-any-screen-resolution), although you might find the [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48606760/15906967) better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to add: [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```
#sky-video {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width and height for the video container first.
Your container now is  then:

```
body {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
}

body #sky-video {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```