# I want to make the background video full screen in css

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm adding a video to my project, but no matter what I do, its size doesn't exceed certain limits. I want to make the video full screen

Here is my css code

```
#myvideo{
     position: fixed;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Share your HTML code as well, please

Comment: Hope this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71911624/fitting-background-video/71911754#71911754

Comment: <body>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="walk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

Comment: Please share the full code. Your CSS code is work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myvideo{
     position: fixed;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 100%;

}
```

just on your html make sure the video id is same on css myvideo not myVideo:

```
<body> <video autoplay muted loop id="myvideo"> <source src="walk.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Comment: oh ahahaha silly me

Comment: Ok you can vote my response